# Keep a reference of a DOM node when mounting / unmounting a React component in a non-React application

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm using webpack to use react components in a non-react applications. The idea is to export these in a way so they can be mounted and dismounted on any DOM.

This is the html page where I'm testing the component:

```php
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/javascripts/build/component.js') ?>"></script>
<button onclick="showComponent()" />show component</button>
<button onclick="hideComponent()" />hide component</button>
<div id='mainContainer'></div>

<script >
  function showComponent() {
    MyComponent.mount(document.getElementById('mainContainer'))
  }

  function hideComponent() {
    MyComponent.unmount()
  }
</script>
```

This is the webpack entry point:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from '/path/to/MyComponent'
import ComponentMounter from '/path/to/ComponentMounter'

let componentMounter = new ComponentMounter(<MyComponent />)

export let mount = componentMounter.mount
export let unmount = componentMounter.unmount
```

In the webpack config, I'm exporting the bundle as a library, using:

```json
output: {
    path: './assets/javascripts/build/',
    filename: 'component.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'MyComponent'
}
```

The ComponentMounter class:

```jsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class ComponentMounter {

  constructor(component) {
    this.component = component
  }

  mount = (element) => {
    // This renders the react 'component', mounting it in the DOM 'element'
    this.element = ReactDOM.render(this.component, element)
  }

  unmount = () => {
    // This unmounts the react 'component', removing the DOM 'element'
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.element)
  }

}

export default ComponentMounter
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do there. When clicking on the show button, the component mounts without problems.

But when I try to unmount it, it seems the element is not a valid DOM element, as I get this warning:

`invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

How can I keep a reference to a React component mounted in a DOM node within ComponentMounter object so I can easily unmount it when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `this.element` to be the result of ReactDOM.render which is incorrect.  Simply change your `mount` function in `ComponentMounter` class to the following to solve your problem:

```
mount = (element) => {
    this.element = element;
    ReactDOM.render(this.component, this.element);
}
```

This is because you want to call `unmountComponentAtNode` on the parent DOM node wheras previously you were setting `this.element` to the return value of `ReactDOM.render` which returns a reference to the component you mounted (or null) and NOT the dom node where the component is mounted.

Comment: Your answer seems to go in the good direction (I had missread the docs for `ReactDOM.render`), but I think there is another issue:  It seems that the value of `this.element` is `undefined` when the `unmount` function is invoked.  I'm checking this by adding debugger breakpoints when the `mount` and `unmount` functions are called, and echoing the value of `this.element'.  The funny thing is, that it also happens with `this.component`, it seems to be `undefined` when invoking the `mount` function, but somehow the component mounts just fine.

Comment: In fact, never mind. It was an unrelated issue. Your answer was just right. Thanks!